# CakePHP JOIN not working

Tags: php, cakephp, join

I am new in cakephp and I have searched a lot but couldn't get the solution. My query is not returning any error but it doesn't join the zone table with the disposeTemp table.

```
public function disposePreview(){

$this->loadModel('DisposeTemp');
$joins = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'zones',                                                                                
        'alias' => 'Zone',                                                                                
        'type' => 'inner',                                                                                                                                                                
        'conditions' => array('DisposeTemp.zone = Zone.id')
    )
);
$options = array(
    'conditions' => array('DisposeTemp.is_delete' => 0,'DisposeTemp.status'=>2),
    'order' => array('Item.item_category_id' => 'asc'),
    'joins' => $joins
);                                         
$getDT = $this->DisposeTemp->find('all', $options);
debug($getDT);
exit;
}
```

Comment: Do you have Debug enabled in config file?

Comment: Also specify cakephp version you use.

Comment: Yes debug is enabled. CakePHP version 2.6.2

Comment: Use "pr($this->DisposeTemp->getDataSource()->getLog());" to view raw sql. what did you see?

Comment: And I think. If you want to see data from Zone. You have to define fields => array('Zone.*') in $options

Comment: Yes! after mentioning Zone.* in fields I have got the zone table, thanks @BànChânTrần , but I didn't get why It wouldn't come at the first place, as I am requesting for all tables? Could you enlighten me a bit ? TIA.

Comment: "In CakePHP, some associations (belongsTo and hasOne) perform automatic joins to retrieve data, so you can issue queries to retrieve models based on data in the related one." - In this case, I think we just have to mention if we want to retrieve data. More detail at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Answer (score 0):

Set foreign key false , as you are not having proper naming convention for foreign key in `DisposeTemp` table , it was supposed to be `zone_id` to auto form relationship.

Now in your situation Use.

```
$joins = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'zones',                                                                                
        'alias' => 'Zone',                                                                                
        'type' => 'inner',       
        'foreignKey' => FALSE,                                                                                                                                                         
        'conditions' => array('DisposeTemp.zone = Zone.id')
    )
);
```

Comment: I have used 'foreignKey' => FALSE earlier but still it's not working. Later I have used bindModel method, it worked for me. Nevertheless thank you !